# Newbie here! How to create a detail page activity for a list view item, without including an action bar in it? Help required

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I need to create a detail page activity which will open on clicking a list view item. I want no action-bar in its layout and there is image which starts on top and ends at middle and have a back button on its top left corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in 3 steps:

1. For creating detail activity page I used an adapter class to fetch all the data from server
2. FOr no ActionBar I made a custom action bar, set it to transparent, changed my app theme by calling a Parent theme and then modified for primary, primary Dark and accent colors in theme style. and then set it on top in my activity's XML layout and called it programmatically using getSupportActionBar() method in OnCreate() of activity
3. For Image with no action bar, I created a transparent action bar and set the the image and action bar in FrameLayout which put one view on another and set the parent activity of this activity in AndroidManifest file for back button.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to hide the actionbar in a certain activity. First you could do it programmatically like this for example in your onCreate() method in the activity where you don't want to have an actionbar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

And the second way is to do it with xml in your android manifest xml-file like this for example:

```
<activity android:name=".DetailsActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> <!--or android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoActionBar">-->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```